# bokeh 0.8.2 - None of the bokeh-server glyph examples rendering the plot

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I have Python 3.4.3 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit) on linux and bokeh 0.8.2. None of the bokeh-server examples in

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/glyphs

are rendering the plot. I can see the widgets and interact with them, but no plot is rendered. The Javascript console says:

Bokeh: could not set initial ranges

I tried with multiple browsers (Chrome, IE and Firefox) with no success. Anyone has a solution to this?

Comment: Without a log or more info it's quite hard to try any guess. I'd suggest you to open an issue on GitHub with useful information like log of the server and the example script. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, we have folks on the team who can reproduce this, and others who can't. All the examples were tested with packages available at the time of the release, so our best current guess is that some updated dependency introduced some incompatibility. We are still working to figure out what that might be.

Comment: I have the same issue, Python 2.7.8, Bokeh 0.9 (just updated). No plots which involve the bokeh-server render the data.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after 0.8.2 a change was made that simplified "auto ranging" significantly. However, older versions of Bokeh are not *forward*-compatible with this change. You need to run the version of the example that came out with the release:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.8.2/examples/glyphs/data_tables_server.py

Alternatively you can install a newer version of Bokeh (0.9 or newer).

Comment: Using the examples in the 0.8.2 release, I can see the plots being rendered now but there are no updates when I interact with the widgets; the plot stays stuck at the initial state.

Comment: OK, I would suggest filing an issue on the Bokeh GH issue tracker with as much information as possible about browser, OS, platform, version, etc. because this will require more investigation, to try and actually duplicate the behavior you are seeing. Note that 0.9 will be released on Thursday, it might also be good to check with this latest release when it is available.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and solved by clearing the browser's cache, as per this post on Bokeh's discussion group:

https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!msg/bokeh/4ipIS0lariw/qmWzVSKHCAAJ